# asp.net file upload web service - could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, file-upload

i'm currently trying to create a file upload web service using visual studio 2012. but my code returns "could not find a part of the path" + my path.

my path exists 100%.

here's the code:

web service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.ComponentModel;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class OGcloud : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{

public OGcloud () {}

[WebMethod]
public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath
                    ("~/TransientStorage/") + fileName, FileMode.Create);
        ms.WriteTo(fs);
        ms.Close();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();

        return "OK";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

public partial class User_MyParking : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string msg = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["loct"] != null)
    {
        byte[] f = OGcloud_Upload.FileBytes;
        OGcloud.OGcloudSoapClient access = new OGcloud.OGcloudSoapClient();
        msg = access.UploadFile(f, OGcloud_Upload.FileName);
    }
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
}
}
```

the aspx form:

```
    <table class="Casual Center" dir="rtl" style="border-spacing:10px">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="loct" id="loct"   style="width:300px"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><textarea id="info" name="info" draggable="false" style="width:950px; height:150px; resize:none;" class="Casual"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="Err_info"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" runat="server">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="OGcloud_Upload" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `Server.MapPath()`

Comment: Which line of code returns that error?

Comment: thank you for your answers! i tried to find the line that returns the error and discovered that apperently the fileupload gives me "c://fakepath/file" instead of the actual file path. i searched online but can't find a way to fix it and get the actual path...

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the file upload is correct. It is a security risk for the web service to see actually paths on a client machine. You have access to the contents of the file so there is no need for the specific path.

This is your code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(
    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/TransientStorage/") + 
                   fileName, 
                FileMode.Create);
```

This is the correct code (assuming you are "using System.IO" at the top of the file) is as follows:

```
// Make sure TransientStorage exists in your virtual folder root
string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(
                     @"~/TransientStorage");
string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
string fullyQualifiedFill = Path.Combine(path, filenameOnly);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullyQualifiedFill, FileMode.Create);
```

Please also make use of IDisposable:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f))
{
    using (FileStream fs = <see code above> )
    {
        ms.WriteTo(fs);
        fs.Flush(); // may not be needed but better to be safe
        fs.Close();
    }

    ms.Close();
}
```

FYI: Know IDisposable... It is asked in EVERY C# interview.